# Retrieving State Heightmaps (DMTED) - Accuracy possible with QGIS? - Requesting Steps

Tags: qgis, export, masking

I need a gmted2010 height map of Massachusetts.  Only Massachusetts, including its shoreline, islands, and of course state boundaries.

What I am currently doing, in bullet point form:

I am using https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ - this is where I select a predefined area to get Mass.  Though it sounds like I will get the option to download a Mass heightmap, I get the entire New England area + more.

Once I have options to download the heightmap, I have selected the 7.5 arc.

I input all heightmap files into QGIS, where they all layer on top of one another.

I retrieve the Shapefile from Mass.gov - I am using the 25k Polygon for the stat of MA.

I select the Open Datasource Manager and select Vector and upload the 25k polygon.
In the processing toolbox I select clip raster by mask layer.

Once I get the "final image" I am left with an image that does not follow the border around states, the shoreline, and outlying islands.  Rather I get the raster effect.  I have added two pictures below so you can see what's going wrong.

Essentially, I need the heightmap of Massachusetts.  I am making some mistakes along the way.  I think it might have to do with how the image from USGS is a raster, and I am using a polygon in Vector form.

In other words, the idea is that the heightmap should be identical to the mask. I should be able to export a high quality TIFF of that heightmap.

Would someone be able to provide a step by step process of how I might be able to get a heightmap of Massachusetts? (or other state or select location, and not have parts/area missing through raster in my "final image."

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please define "heightmap".  I think you mean a Digital Elevation Model (DEM), but I may be wrong.  If you did download a DEM, which version (DMTED, GTOPO, SRTM...)?

Comment: Yes I mean DEM. I used the DMTED2010.

Answer (score 0):

"...I am left with an image that does not follow the border around states, the shoreline, and outlying islands. Rather I get the raster effect."

DEM data ***is*** raster data, so you will naturally (and correctly!) end up with "...the raster effect."

Because of the DEM's inherent raster nature, you can only get the pixelated, stair-step look with such data.  It will never exactly follow the non-orthogonal angles that vector data can display (such as your coastline).  However, you can more closely *approximate* such vector boundaries by sourcing raster data with a smaller pixel size, which in turn reduce (but not eliminate) the raster effect.